# How to manually complete the stripe checkout session from backend for testing?

Tags: stripe-payments

I am writing tests for how the billing system reacts to various events in Stripe. In our backend tests there is a mode to run billing tests so that it talks to Stripe API instead of using fixtures. And it saves responses from Stripe automatically as fixtures. This means you only need to run tests in fixture generation mode when there are changes made to the Stripe API or billing system.

The tricky part ofcourse is to see how the system reacts to webhook events from Stripe. The workaround I found is to use the stripe events API endpoint to fetch the recent events and post it to the webhook endpoint. You can make this work for pretty much all the important events. For example attaching a valid a PaymentMethod to a PaymentIntent will result in a  `payment_intent.succeeded` event. And you can get that event using `stripe.Event.list` and send the event to the webhook the billing system to emulate the event.

The event I am having a toruble generating is the `checkout.session.completed` event. Since it looks like you can generate the event only after going through Stripe checkout which is not possible in backend. Ofocurse, you can create a fake event like this

```py
 [checkout_setup_intent] = stripe.SetupIntent.list(limit=1)
        stripe_setup_intent = stripe.SetupIntent.create(
            payment_method=payment_method.id,
            confirm=True,
            payment_method_types=checkout_setup_intent.payment_method_types,
            customer=checkout_setup_intent.customer,
            metadata=checkout_setup_intent.metadata,
            usage=checkout_setup_intent.usage,
        )
        [stripe_session] = stripe.checkout.Session.list(limit=1)
        stripe_session_dict = stripe_session.to_dict_recursive()
        stripe_session_dict["setup_intent"] = stripe_setup_intent.id

        event_payload = {
            "object": "event",
            "data": {"object": stripe_session_dict},
            "type": "checkout.session.completed",
        }
```

But that is less than ideal. Is there a way to trigger the `checkout.session.completed` event with real data and without the need of a web ui?

Answer (score 1):

My solution was to use e2e testing (with cypress) to complete payment, and call it from my integration testing code.

This takes around 10 seconds to complete.

NUnit test:

```
var paymentUrl = "https://checkout.stripe.com/pay/cs_test_a1nqdPnsxtq.......";
        Process process = new Process();
        process.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = @"C:\PathToCypress";
        process.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
        process.StartInfo.Arguments = $"/c npx cypress run --env url={paymentUrl}";
        process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
        process.Start();
        process.WaitForExit();
```

Cypress script:

```
describe('Stripe Billing', () => {
    it('Completes a checkout session', () => {
        cy.visit(Cypress.env('url'));

        // Enter billing details
        cy.get('#cardNumber').type('4242424242424242');
        cy.get('#cardExpiry').type('3333');
        cy.get('#cardCvc').type('3333');
        cy.get('#billingName').type('TestName');
        cy.get('.SubmitButton').click();

        // Wait for payment to succeed
        cy.server().route('GET', 'https://api.stripe.com/v1/checkout/sessions/completed_webhook_delivered/*').as('completed'); // define request

        cy.wait('@completed', { timeout: 60000 });
    })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can with the [Stripe CLI](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-cli):

`stripe trigger checkout.sessions.completed`

Comment: That triggers the webhook with sample data right? I am looking for `checkout.sessions.completed` event with real data not sample data. That is the setup_intent of the event should have metadata set by the backend test while creating the session.